Can't start new PostgreSQL installation on Bazzite
I've recently installed Bazzite (an atomic Fedora variant) and want to get PostgreSQL running so I can continue an online development course I'm taking. I opened BoxBuddy (a.k.a. Toolbox) and successfully installed postgresql-server.x86_64 as well as postgresql.x86_64. I tried to run pg_ctl status, but got an error that PGDATA wasn't set. Fine, I set that to /etc/postgresql-setup/upgrade/postgresql.conf since the installation created that file. Now, the problem I get is pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/etc/postgresql-setup/upgrade/postgresql.conf/postmaster.pid": Not a directory. I do not have a postmaster.pid file, and in any case, postgresql.conf isn't a directory, so it couldn't contain a file itself. What has gone wrong here?


PGDATA wasn't set. Fine, I set that to /etc/postgresql-setup/upgrade/postgresql.conf

That's the problem. PGDATA is supposed to be your data directory (e.g., /var/lib/pgsql/data), not your config file.

That helped, I think. Now the process doesn't have access to that directory, even though I've followed the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191483/postgres-not-working-when-i-change-the-data-directory-in-ubuntu. When I try to 'su - postgres' I'm asked for a password. The password for my user account (which I think has root permission) isn't accepted.

@spartanhooah Does sudo su - postgres work any better?

I think so. The prompt now indicates that I'm the user postgres instead of fedora. Now, pg_ctl status results in pg_ctl: directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data" is not a database cluster directory. Should I have done something to that directory first?

@spartanhooah Yes, initdb.

That did it, thank you.
